# Identifying the source of malformed URLs

Tags: .net, html, url, webforms, malformed

We occasionally get errors in the log for our web application saying that a request for a URL was malformed. The URL itself would look something like this: `http://{sampledomain.com}/<br>`. The `<br>` is included as part of the URL.

It appears that the request is coming from Firefox 3.6.17 and Firefox 3.0.19. It also appears that this behavior isn't widespread, but perhaps coming from just a couple of our users.

The default page that exists at the URL without the `<br>` is valid XHTML 1.0 code as verified by the w3c validator, and there is no referrer in the header for these requests.

We've been ignoring these errors, but I'm curious why they occur. They shouldn't occur through normal navigation of the site, and they don't really seem like part of malicious requests to probe for vulnerability. Does anyone know why this happens and what we could do to prevent it?

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: True, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: My point is that if all the links on his own pages that link to `sampledomain.com` are valid XHTML, it cannot be one of his own links that are broken.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: Indeed, good thinking. But the OP already said that the behavior is only occasional, so it's definitely not a bad link.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's a bad link in our site. I would have expected to see a referrer if it were a link on our site.

Comment: Is it possible that someone was managing their bookmarks and introduced a <br> into a bookmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received another error of the same format, but it had a referrer that says: http://app.bluetie.com/ca1759d5/gds/index_rich.php. I am going to assume that these malformed URLs are coming from some kind of link-creating get rich quick scheme and just work to block them. They don't appear to be coming from users doing normal things on my site. If anyone has additional insight, I may still choose their answer to close the question, but otherwise, I'll close the question with this answer in a couple of days.